# ora2pg out of memory error - after every table

Tags: ora2pg

when I try to export data, it runs out of memory, regardless of table size (even empty tables.)

```
Out of memory!            ]    162926/498508267 rows (0.0%) on total estimated data (14 sec., avg: 11637 recs/sec)
Issuing rollback() due to DESTROY without explicit disconnect() of DBD::Oracle::db handle (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PORT=1521)(HOST=192.168.0.42)
(PROTOCOL=tcp))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl))) at 
/usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2/DBD/Oracle.pm line 348.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asking the author, I got this response:

> You don't have enough memory. If you can't increase the memory size than reduce the value of DATA_LIMIT in ora2pg.conf. Try with 5000 and if it doesn't works use 2500.

Opened `./config/ora2pg.conf` and modfied set `DATA_LIMIT 5000` solved the issue.

I originally tried to add more RAM, but only doubled it from 2GB to 4GB, it did not help.  Reducing the `DATA_LIMIT` was the solution.